# backoff_tagger not defined error

Tags: tags, nltk

Hi I'm trying to use Brill Tagger to tag a set of sentences. But when running the following ,

=======================

## Training a Brill Tagger

```
>>> default_tagger = DefaultTagger('NN')
>>> initial_tagger = backoff_tagger(train_sents, [UnigramTagger,     BigramTagger, TrigramTagger], backoff=default_tagger)
>>> initial_tagger.evaluate(test_sents)
0.8806820634578028
>>> from tag_util import train_brill_tagger
>>> brill_tagger = train_brill_tagger(initial_tagger, train_sents)
>>> brill_tagger.evaluate(test_sents)
0.8827541549751781
```

I'm getting the following error.

NameError: name 'backoff_tagger' is not defined

what are the causes for this. Do I need to import something

Comment: Where did you get the code above from? Is it from NLTK or some other NLTK wrapper. It doesn't look lke it's from NLTK. Because all taggers are classses. I would expect the backoff tagger to be a class with CamelCase too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to import the following:

```
from tag_util import backoff_tagger
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tag_util'`